# Разбить строку на триады

Tags: java, jsp

Всем привет, недавно задавал этот вопрос, мне помог `@Sergey Gornostaev`, но вот тестировал, и нашел проблемку, когда в строке не числа, а слова или пустые поля, данные перестают выводится на страницу и выдается ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException at Bean.TriadBean.setChunks(TriadBean.java:46)`, может кто знает как исправить?

Вот пример бина:

```java
public class TriadBean {
    private String[] chunks;
    private String delimiter;
    private int size;

    public String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
        if (delimiter == null || delimiter.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Разделитель должен быть установлен!");

        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer size) {
        if (size < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Размер группы должен быть положительным числом!");

        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setChunks(String src) {
        if (delimiter == null || size == 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Не установлен разделитель или размер группы!");

        int chunksCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) src.length() / (double) size);
        chunks = new String[chunksCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++)
            chunks[i] = src.substring(i * size, Math.min(src.length(), (i + 1) * size));
    }

    public String getChunks() {
        if (chunks == null)
            return "";

        return Arrays.stream(chunks)
                .map(String::trim)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
    }
}
```

На `jsp` делал так:

```
<jsp:useBean id="grouper" class="Bean.TriadBean">
    <jsp:setProperty name="grouper" property="delimiter" value="-"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="grouper" property="size" value="3"/>
</jsp:useBean>
<c:set target="${grouper}" property="chunks" value="${vp44150sql.nc}" />
<c:out value="${grouper.chunks}"/>
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` этот код выдаёт только в том случае, если значение `vp44150sql.nc` равно `null`.

Comment: а можно как-то сделать так, что бы оно продолжало выводить данные в таблицу, а то маршрут не всегда есть, а из-за этого просто получается страничка не отображается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<jsp:useBean id="grouper" class="Bean.TriadBean">
   <jsp:setProperty name="grouper" property="delimiter" value="-"/>
   <jsp:setProperty name="grouper" property="size" value="3"/>
</jsp:useBean>

<c:if test="${not empty vp44150sql.nc}">
    <c:set target="${grouper}" property="chunks" value="${vp44150sql.nc}" />
    <c:out value="${grouper.chunks}"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает как нужно, а можно как-то пробелы убрать которые перед и после символа "/" маршрут `32-33-936-32 / 32-43`?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

```java
String text = "ladhjsfdkjsfhlakjsdhe331.235145v1hj2v34j1v34";
text = text.replaceAll("(.{3})","$1 ");
System.out.println(text);
// lad hjs fdk jsf hla kjs dhe 331 .23 514 5v1 hj2 v34 j1v 34
```

Comment: там есть пробелы в полях, этим способом добавляются лишние пробелы, и плюс еще нужно пробелы заменить на "-"

Comment: вот так выглядит маршрут `-32 -33 936 -32 /-32` а должно быть `32-33-936-32/32`