# Разделение строки по 3 символа

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

В данной строчке кода (в теории) должен объявляться массив, в который присваивается огромное предложение без пробелов, разделённое по три символа (случаи, когда кол-во символов в предложении не кратно трём отбросим). Почему-то не пашет регулярное выражение и в массив присваивается пустота.

```
String text="111222333444555666777888999aaabbbcccdddeeefff"
String[] triples = text.split("\\S{3}");
```

Comment: Возможно сплит не совсем так работает, попробуйте использовать `matches`. Возможно я не совсем правильно понял вопрос, лучше отредактировать вопрос добавив примеры

Comment: Почитайте что именно делает стр.сплит()

Comment: Разделяет строку на подстроки исходя из написанного regex'а, разве нет?

Comment: Да, но не так, как вы думаете. Разделитель  в результат не попадает. Именно это вы и получаете.

Comment: Да, понял уже что жутко затупил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `split` сделает разделение по строке и вернет массив строк, без разделителя, поэтому этот метод может вам не подойти.

Используйте матчинг через `Pattern.matcher`:

```
String text = "111222333444555666777888999aaabbbcccdddeeefff";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S{3}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);

List<String> triples = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    triples.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(triples);
// [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Только понял что жутко тупанул с использованием сплита

Comment: @nikilum, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала добавить пробелы через каждые 3 символа, а потом разделить по ним:

```java
String text = "111222333444555666777888999aaabbbcccdddeeefff";
String[] triples = text.replaceAll("(.{3})","$1 ").split(" ");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(triples));
// [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff]
```

---

См. [Разбить строку на триады](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754464/236980)